# error while importing SBT sources - [error] (/:dumpStructure) java.net.URISyntaxException:

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have an error when I try to import a new sbt/scala project into IntelliJ IDEA :

> [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.15 ...
>   [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.12.2 ...
>   [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.12.2 ...
>   [info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-xml_2.12;1.0.6 ...
>   [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.12.2 ...
>   [info] Resolving jline#jline;2.14.3 ...
>   [error] (*/*:dumpStructure) java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 23: file:/C:/Users/Marouane AYAD/.sbt/preloaded/
>   [error] Total time: 1 s, completed 26 juil. 2017 00:18:38
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384M; support was removed in 8.0

any ideas what is cause of this problem ?

Comment: My bet is on the blank: `/Marouane AYAD/`.

Comment: This question has enough information to answer. This was a bug in the IntelliJ Scala plugin / sbt interaction and will be fixed in an upcoming release. Reference: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-12292

Answer (score 1):

Use a path without spaces. Instead of `C:/Users/Marouane AYAD/.sbt/preloaded/` use eg. `C:/Users/Marouane_AYAD/.sbt/preloaded/`. Space is not allowed in URI syntax. Alternatively, if your configuration allows it, you can URI-encode the space as `%20`, so `Marouane%20AYAD`.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, i'm using intellij on a fedora VM Now .. and it works much better :)